# Обращения к блоку по номеру

Tags: html, css

столкнулся с проблемой , есть код -

html

```css
.wrapper>.block {
  background-color: black;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

.wrapper>.active:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper>.active:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block active"></div>
  <div class="block active"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

по идеи 3 - 4 блок должны поменять цвета , но они не меняют , смена цветов сработает только если клас `active` переместить на первый блок .

Comment: Они являются третьим и четвёртым потомками, значит должно быть `nth-child(3)` и `nth-child(4)` соответственно

Comment: Я это заметил, но мне нужно ссылаться именно на первый `active` и второй, я не знаю, где они будут, есть способ это сделать?

Comment: Если именно первый и второй, то потребуется три правила. Для первого: `.wrapper > .active`, для второго: `.wrapper > .active ~ .active`, и для всех остальных: `.wrapper > .active ~ .active ~ .active`. Такова жизнь...

Comment: спасибо , помогло , но тут да жесть )

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper>.block {
  background-color: black;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

.wrapper > .active {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper > .active ~ .active {
  background-color: pink;
}
```